Want to run python main.exe from different folder not from its default folder where all it’s supported lib and DLL are there
Can we run main.exe from another folder
I tried to include pre existing DLL from shared drive and exclude all its default DLL and lib. But cx_freeze creates lib, DLL, main.exe under default folder . I want to install lib, python39.dll, python3.dll and lib folder remain in default folder but main.exe call these all from shared drive

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
